# Prevent other functions running after selected function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a div #imageSwap and three buttons #button1, #button2, #button3. The first two buttons change the HTML of the div to hold a specific image, the third starts a rotation of multiple images.

For some reason, when the third (rotating) button is clicked it runs fine, but when the first or second button is clicked after the third, the animation runs when it shouldn't.

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  setImageOne();
  $('#button1').addClass('selected');     


  $("a#button1").click(function() {

       setImageOne();           
          $(this).addClass('selected');
          $('#button2').removeClass('selected');
          $('#button3').removeClass('selected');
      });

  $("a#button2").click(function() {

       commObj();
          $(this).addClass('selected');
          $('#button1').removeClass('selected');
          $('#button3').removeClass('selected');
      });

  $("a#button3").click(function() {

           comProg();
          $(this).addClass('selected');
          $('#button1').removeClass('selected');
          $('#button2').removeClass('selected');
       });
 });

function setImageOne() {
  $('#imageSwap').fadeIn(500).html('<img src="slide1.png" />');   
}


function commObj() {
  $('#imageSwap').fadeIn(500).html('<img src="co.png" />');
}


function comProg() {
  $('#imageSwap').fadeIn(500).html('<img src="bo2.png" />').delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function () { comProg2(); });
}
function comProg2() {
  $('#imageSwap').fadeIn(500).html('<img src="bo2.png" />').delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function () { comProg3(); });
}
function comProg3() {
  $('#imageSwap').fadeIn(500).html('<img src="bo2.png" />').delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function () { comProg4(); });
}
function comProg4() {
  $('#imageSwap').fadeIn(500).html('<img src="bo2.png" />').delay(2000).fadeOut(500,           function () { comProg(); });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because all your comProg functions have a callback function that calls a comProg function and because of that the animation will run every 2 seconds.

And btw you can write `comProg2` instead of `function () { comProg2(); }` although all your comProg functions are same you could just use one function and use a callback that would call the same function instead of the next function which does the same thing...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - new to jQuery so all advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

check out jquery animation queue http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 0):

Add something like

```
$('#imageSwap').clearQueue();
```

in the callback handlers for button 1 and button 2 to stop the endless animation.

See http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/